# How to split a list to obtain the power set of its elements?

Tags: algorithm, partitioning, powerset

I have a list and I want to split it into sub lists with +/- 1 items.

Example

I have a list with 17 items in it. What I want is to split it into 4 sub lists like these

```
1.List = 5 elements
2.List = 4 elements
3.List = 4 elements
4.List = 4 elements
```

How can I do that? What algorithm I should use here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use integer division to get the items in each group and then use modular division to get the number of the first n groups that will have +1 item. For example:
17 items into 4 groups:

- `17 / 4 = 4` - So there will be 4 groups with 4 elements.
- `17 % 4 = 1` - So the first 1 groups will have an additional 1 element.

Another example:

- `18 / 4 = 4` - So there will be 4 groups with 4 elements.
- `18 % 4 = 2` - So the first 2 groups will have an additional 1 element.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is the **Power Set** of your original list. The more generic approach for retrieving the power set and the respective properties are given at the [Power Set page at Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set)